# Почему фон не становится на место?

Tags: html, css, background

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должен ставать так фон, но он становится по другому.

Вот так добавляю фон:

```
background: url(../img/low_bg.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
min-height: 340px;
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Вот как в итоге выходит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: очевидно, что свойство `background-size: cover` растягивает его на весь блок

Comment: @РашенБеар
Да, но ведь блок не намного больше реального размера картинки, которую я вставляю на фон. Картинка не должна до такой степени увеличиваться.

Comment: инспектор кода в помощь

Comment: @РашенБеар, футер нормальной ширины, если вы про это, он не растянут непонятно куда, причина почему фон так становится мне не известна.

Comment: ну так инспектор кода покажет

Comment: Прочитай документацию свойства background-position, оно должно помочь.

Comment: background-position: center top;

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
background: url(../img/low_bg.jpg);
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
min-height: 340px;
```